# Bridging a wired LAN to a WLAN with a static IP

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, lan, ubuntu-16.04

I've got a PC connected to a wired LAN that has a very slow WiFi adapter. I can connect to the network directly, but this is far too slow for my use case (a lot of sensor data is being transferred). I have another PC with a faster WiFi adapter that I can connect to the LAN the first computer is on (via Ethernet) and I'd like to use that computer as a bridge between the two networks.

Diagram below:
[image: Network setup]

Is there any way I can do this?

Edit: Tim Stewart linked a similar question which included a link to [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29) instructions. I followed them, but there is a difference in my setup that I hadn't included in the question.

Network A is on the subnet 192.168.x.x, Network B is on the subnet 172.20.x.x. My sensor computer has been assigned a static IP on network B which I can change, but because of bureaucracy getting it changed can take weeks. How can I use the assigned static IP on my computer in network A?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/121740/how-to-properly-set-up-a-network-bridge-using-bridge-utils-using-wlan0-as-the-in

Comment: It looks like your question has already been answered...

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Thanks, I couldn't find any similar questions when I looked. I added some more information to the main question about why this is different.

Comment: In the picture, your “sensor computer” is in network A, yet you write it has been assigned an IP address on network B? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, it's been assigned an IP to connect to network B. I can connect to network B via WiFi, but the adapter on the sensor computer is too slow for sending the data that I need. To work around that, I'm trying to use a laptop as a gateway to network B which will hopefully provide a faster connection. I should note that network B is white-listed, and only machines with the right combination of host name and IP can use it.

Comment: I see. Well then you cannot use the assigned address. Simple as that. Does the “sensor computer” actually *send* data to a specific location?

Comment: Hm, I might have to look for another solution then. In this case, the "sensor computer" is the central computer of a robot using ROS (which runs over TCP/IP), which then sends the sensor data to an external computer for processing (the external computer has a GPU for faster neural network processing) and the external computer sends back the results of the processing. The robot's internal network is network A and the computer used for processing is on network B.

Comment: Why not use a wireless bridge? It would do exactly what you are trying to do. Take Ethernet network in, and combine the two via wireless.